# Direct link to a SonarQube Widget

Tags: widget, sonarqube

I've been looking for a way to directly access a widget from my SonarQube instance with a direct URL, the way it's possible to access a Dashboard. Is it possible to do that adding the respective metrics from the configuration of the Widget? The problem I found is that I can only "build" a widget and it takes the **filter** parameter, **sizes**, but when it comes to the metrics, they are ignored and it builds it with the default ones for the respective widget.

I have the following Widget configured (with metrics: Classes, Comment_Density and size - Complexity):
[image]

When building the URL to get directly this widget, I found it impossible to access it by its Id. So, I added all configuration details, but the widget I get is this, holding the default metrics - Lines of Code, Issues and Technical Debt. Built widget:
[image]

Is accessing directly a configured Widget even possible with the current versions of the SonarQube?
The URL I used is :

```
<sonarqubeinstance>/widget?id=measure_filter_bubble_chart&filter=1&chartTitle=Measure%20Bubble%20Chart&chartHeight=400&widget_width=1279px&metric1=classes&metric2=comment_lines_density&metric3=complexity
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you try to achieve is not possible.

What's more, keep in mind that those widgets do not exist any more starting with SonarQube 6.2. And there is no plan to reintroduce them.

Comment: Hi Fabrice,thanks for your prompt feedback! What we're are trying to do is embed/integrate the reports (widgets) we have in our SonarQube Instance as images into another Corporate web platform. So far we haven't found a way to do that and there is not much official documentation on Integrating SonarQube with other reporting applications. Can you point me the right direction to investigate possibilities in order to achieve this task? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best (and actually only good) way to embed results from SonarQube into a third-party application is to use the Web Service API to query SonarQube: https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/web-service-api.html

Comment: I see, yes, that seems the best approach to go for. I also saw Kibana developed Plugin for such integration.  Thanks a lot Fabrice! Greetings from Barcelona!